# How to convert nested Oracle SQL statement to pySpark SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle, pyspark, subquery

Trying to convert this Oracle SQL statement into SQL:

```
SELECT 
FROM
  P_TIME_PERIODS  TP_RaisedDate,
  P_DCF_ACTIVITY,
  INM_ACTIVITIES,
  P_FINANCE_GROUPS,
  P_CREW_HQS,
  P_ACTIVITY_CODES,
  P_ACTIVITIES,
  (SELECT
  DISTINCT
  M_WW_TWRKAE00.CDE_dist,
  M_WW_TWRKAE00.CDE_WR,
(SELECT DECODE(a.TXT_VALUE,NULL,a.FLG_VALUE,a.TXT_VALUE)  FROM M_WW_TWRKAE00  a WHERE M_WW_TWRKAE00.cde_dist=a.cde_dist AND M_WW_TWRKAE00.cde_wr=a.cde_wr AND a.CDE_ATTRIBUTE='E911') ""Right1"",
 (SELECT DECODE(a.TXT_VALUE,NULL,a.FLG_VALUE,a.TXT_VALUE)  FROM M_WW_TWRKAE00  a WHERE M_WW_TWRKAE00.cde_dist=a.cde_dist AND M_WW_TWRKAE00.cde_wr=a.cde_wr AND a.CDE_ATTRIBUTE='E912') ""Left1"",
 (SELECT DECODE(a.TXT_VALUE,NULL,a.FLG_VALUE,a.TXT_VALUE)  FROM M_WW_TWRKAE00  a WHERE M_WW_TWRKAE00.cde_dist=a.cde_dist AND M_WW_TWRKAE00.cde_wr=a.cde_wr AND a.CDE_ATTRIBUTE='E913') ""Minor1"",
 (SELECT DECODE(a.TXT_VALUE,NULL,a.FLG_VALUE,a.TXT_VALUE)  FROM M_WW_TWRKAE00  a WHERE M_WW_TWRKAE00.cde_dist=a.cde_dist AND M_WW_TWRKAE00.cde_wr=a.cde_wr AND a.CDE_ATTRIBUTE='E914') ""Major1"",
```

`

Comment: Into _which_ SQL?

Comment: Spark SQL. Working in databricks

Comment: or into sql server. The converting the select DECODE is into a CASE STATEMEnt is my issue at the moment @jarlh

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions040.htm

Comment: This is not valid Oracle SQL.  It has an empty `SELECT` clause.

Answer (score 0):

`DECODE(a.TXT_VALUE,NULL,a.FLG_VALUE,a.TXT_VALUE)`

should be identical to

`CASE WHEN a.TXT_VALUE IS NULL THEN a.FLG_VALUE ELSE a.TXT_VALUE END`

but can be simplified to

`COALESCE(a.TXT_VALUE, a.FLG_VALUE)`

which works in both Spark SQL and SQL Server.

Comment: "thanks". How should I approach a WHERE M_WW_TWRKAE00.cde_dist=a.cde_dist AND M_WW_TWRKAE00.cde_wr=a.cde_wr AND a.CDE_ATTRIBUTE='E911') ""Right1"" which is creating a column based on the specific condition

Comment: just use it as it is. does that give any error?